# TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined React Native Redux

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, reducers

I have attempted to create a reducer, following the same logic of an example I had working with git repos

Here is said reducer:

```
/**
 * Created by kenji on 3/9/18.
 */
/**
 * /stock?search=String
 * Searches Stock table, checking for given search value
 * and returns an array that contains that value
 * @action GET
 * @returns [array]
 * @type {string}
 */
export const GET_STOCK_LIST = 'ReduxStarter/stock_list/LOAD';
export const GET_STOCK_LIST_SUCCESS = 'ReduxStarter/stock_list/LOAD_SUCCESS';
export const GET_STOCK_LIST_FAIL = 'ReduxStarter/stock_list/LOAD_FAILURE';

/**
 * /stock/${id}
 * Gets an ID passed to it and returns an object if it exists
 * @action GET
 * @returns {object}
 * @type {string}
 */
export const GET_STOCK = 'ReduxStarter/stock/LOAD';
export const GET_STOCK_SUCCESS = 'ReduxStarter/stock/LOAD_SUCCESS';
export const GET_STOCK_FAIL = 'ReduxStarter/stock/LOAD_FAIL';

/**
 * /stock/${id}
 * Updates Stock by passing an object with new variables to update with
 * @action PUT
 * @returns {null}
 * @type {string}
 */
export const PUT_STOCK = 'ReduxStarter/stock/CHANGE';
export const PUT_STOCK_SUCCESS = 'ReduxStarter/stock/CHANGE_SUCCESS';
export const PUT_STOCK_FAIL = 'ReduxStarter/stock/CHANGE_FAIL';

/**
 * /stock/${id}/barcodes
 * Gets the barcodes of an a stock item if the ID is valid
 * @action: GET
 * @returns [array]
 * @type {string}
 */
export const GET_BARCODES = 'ReduxStarter/stock/barcodes/LOAD';
export const GET_BARCODES_SUCCESS = 'ReduxStarter/stock/barcodes/LOAD_SUCCESS';
export const GET_BARCODES_FAIL = 'ReduxStarter/stock/barcodes/LOAD_FAIL';

/**
 * /stock/barcode/${barcode}
 * Gets a stock item from the supplied barcode
 * @action: GET
 * @returns [array]
 * @type {string}
 */
export const GET_STOCK_FROM_BARCODE = 'ReduxStarter/stock/barcode/LOAD';
export const GET_STOCK_FROM_BARCODE_SUCCESS = 'ReduxStarter/stock/barcode/LOAD_SUCCESS';
export const GET_STOCK_FROM_BARCODE_FAIL = 'ReduxStarter/stock/barcode/LOAD_FAIL';

const initialState = {
    stockList: [],
    stock: {},
    result: {},
    barcodeList: [],
    stockFromBarcode: {},
};

export default function reducer(state = initialState, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case GET_STOCK_LIST:
            return { ...state, loadingStockList: true };
        case GET_STOCK_LIST_SUCCESS:
            return { ...state, loadingStockList: false, stockList: action.payload.data };
        case GET_STOCK_LIST_FAIL:
            return { ...state, loadingStockList: false, stockListError: 'Failed to retrieve stock list' };
        case GET_STOCK:
            return { ...state, loadingStock: true };
        case GET_STOCK_SUCCESS:
            return { ...state, loadingStock: false, stock: action.payload.data };
        case GET_STOCK_FAIL:
            return { ...state, loadingStock: false, stockError: 'Failed to retrieve stock list' };
        case PUT_STOCK:
            return { ...state, loadingStockUpdate: true };
        case PUT_STOCK_SUCCESS:
            return { ...state, loadingStockUpdate: false, result: action.payload.data };
        case PUT_STOCK_FAIL:
            return { ...state, loadingStockUpdate: false, stockUpdateError: 'Failed to update stock list' };
        case GET_BARCODES:
            return { ...state, loadingBarcodes: true };
        case GET_BARCODES_SUCCESS:
            return { ...state, loadingBarcodes: false, barcodeList: action.payload.data };
        case GET_BARCODES_FAIL:
            return { ...state, loadingBarcodes:false, barcodesError: 'Failed to load barcodes' };
        case GET_STOCK_FROM_BARCODE:
            return { ...state, loadingStockFromBarcode: true };
        case GET_STOCK_FROM_BARCODE_SUCCESS:
            return { ...state, loadingStockFromBarcode: false, stockFromBarcode: action.payload.data };
        case GET_STOCK_FROM_BARCODE_FAIL:
            return { ...state, loadingStockFromBarcode: false, stockFromBarcodeError: 'Failed to get stock item from barcode' };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export function listStockArray(searchQuery, pageSize = 50, pageNumber = 1) {
    return {
        type: GET_STOCK_LIST,
        payload: {
            request: {
                url: `/stock?search=${searchQuery}&pageSize=${pageSize}&pageNumber=${pageNumber}`
            }
        }
    };
}

export function listStockItem(stockID) {
    return {
        type: GET_STOCK_LIST,
        payload: {
            request: {
                url: `/stock/${stockID}`
            }
        }
    };
}

export function updateStock(stockID, data) {
    return {
        type: GET_STOCK_LIST,
        payload: {
            request: {
                url: `/stock/${stockID}`,
                method: `PUT`,
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                data: data,
            }
        }
    };
}

export function listStockBarcodes(stockID) {
    return {
        type: GET_BARCODES,
        payload: {
            request: {
                url: `/stock/${stockID}/barcodes`
            }
        }
    };
}

export function listStockFromBarcode(barcode) {
    return {
        type: GET_BARCODES,
        payload: {
            request: {
                url: `/stock/barcode/${barcode}`
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Now i get the error as mentioned in the header:
**TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined **

Here is the implimentation of the reducers to the app:

```
import reducers from './redux/reducers/lots_reducer';
import StockList from './components/StockList';

const client = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'https://api.github.com',
    responseType: 'json'
});

const store = createStore(reducers, applyMiddleware(axiosMiddleware(client)));

const Stack = createStackNavigator({
    StockList: {
        screen: StockList
    },
});

export default class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Provider store={store}>
                <View style={styles.container}>
                    <Stack/>
                </View>
            </Provider>
        );
    }
}
```

And finally the actual component:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import { listStockArray } from '../redux/reducers/lots_reducer';

class StockList extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.listStockArray('panadol');
    }

    renderItem = ({ stockList }) => (
        <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.item}
            onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate(`Detail`, { name: stockList.StockID })}
        >
            <Text>{stockList.TradeName}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    );

    render() {
        const { stockList } = this.props;
        return (
            <FlatList
                styles={styles.container}
                data={stockList}
                renderItem={this.renderItem}
            />
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1
    },
    item: {
        padding: 16,
        borderBottomWidth: 1,
        borderBottomColor: '#ccc'
    }
});

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    let storedRepositories = state.repos.map(repo => ({ key: (repo.id).toString(), ...repo }));
    return {
        repos: storedRepositories
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = {
    listStockArray
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(StockList);
```

Sorry about the large amount of code dumped, its just all related and I believe the error lies somewherewithin having an undefined initialState but I cant see what I have missed defining

Comment: I don't see `repos` defined anywhere in your reducer. Error is pretty clear to me, it tries to call `map()` on something `repos` which in not defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    let storedRepositories = state.repos.map(repo => ({ key: (repo.id).toString(), ...repo }));
    return {
        repos: storedRepositories
    };
};
```

means that you want transform (change `id` to `key` property) state.repos using map function and return as `repos` using intermediate variable `storedRepositories`. These parts looks as original, not changed from repos example.

Error appears because state doesn't contain `repos` array. You have a few other arrays in state (initialState in reducer) but none of them is `repos`.

In reducer you're storing payloads (fetched data) in store arrays, f.e.

```
    case GET_STOCK_LIST_SUCCESS:
        return { ...state, loadingStockList: false, stockList: action.payload.data };
```

stores data in `stockList`. For other succes actions you have other array names.

Component doesn't have to use all store data, you can use only parts it's interested in - this is a reason for `mapStateToProps` mapping. You can have it as simple as

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        stockList: state.stockList, 
        stock: state.stock
    };
};
```

These values will be available as `this.props.stockList` and `this.props.stock`.

Comment: Appreciate it, im very new to redux and it was confusing where I was getting lost this makes alot of sense :)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're not defining `repos` , how do you want to map it ?

```
const initialState = {
  stockList: [],
  stock: {},
  result: {},
  barcodeList: [],
  stockFromBarcode: {},
  repos: []
};
```

Or alternativly , you meant another field .

Answer (score 0):

Because you're trying to use `map` function which works with an array but you `repo` which not array.
There is a possibility that `repo` is not when you are `mapping` it (might be before assigning value).

**Approach** I just check where it is an Array using `Array.isArray()`, if Array then may else return empty array.

As @sagi mentioned, better approach initialize your state with `repo` field as an empty array. basically, this kind of error occurs when

> you try to use array function to non-array element

Comment: Actually, there not mention of `repos` any where in the code but where he uses map .

Comment: Yes, actually he trying to map `undefined`. t